# AS3 Prototypes - are they just static variables?

Tags: actionscript-3

> A reference to the prototype object of a class or function object. The
>   prototype property is automatically created and attached to any class
>   or function object that you create. This property is static in that it
>   is specific to the class or function that you create. For example, if
>   you create a class, the value of the prototype property is shared by
>   all instances of the class and is accessible only as a class property.
>   Instances of your class cannot directly access the prototype property.
>
> A class’s prototype object is a special instance of that class that
>   provides a mechanism for sharing state across all instances of a
>   class. At run time, when a property is not found on a class instance,
>   the delegate, which is the class prototype object, is checked for that
>   property. If the prototype object does not contain the property, the
>   process continues with the prototype object’s delegate checking in
>   consecutively higher levels in the hierarchy until Flash Player or the
>   Adobe Integrated Runtime finds the property.
>
> Note: In ActionScript 3.0, prototype inheritance is not the primary
>   mechanism for inheritance. Class inheritance, which drives the
>   inheritance of fixed properties in class definitions, is the primary
>   inheritance mechanism in ActionScript 3.0.

So, from this I get the impression that prototypes are just static variables.. am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly, a function implemented as a prototype is still executed as instance method. In a static function you don't have access to `this`.

Also it doesn't mean setting a prototype value to something is setting the value for every instance. It's only the fallback value, if an object of that class isn't setting it explicitly.

```
var o1:Object= {};
var o2:Object= {};
Object.prototype.foo = "foo";

o1.foo = "bar"

trace(o1.foo) // bar
trace(o2.foo) // foo
```